# Problem with running Storybook on Nuxt V3

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, storybook, nuxtjs3

I hope you are doing well.

I have issue with running Storybook in Nuxt v3. it seems Nuxt does not support storybook yet. i tried community solutions but none of them works for me. i do not know where is wrong and i can not debug it well as it is my first time to use Storybook as well as Atomic design.

Here is my Nuxt v3 configurations:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-atomic",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".ts,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js && yarn lint:prettier",
    "lintfix": "prettier --write --list-different . && yarn lint:js --fix",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.7.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.7.0",
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.8.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.0",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/vue3-vite": "^7.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.4.1",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^10.4.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.13",
    "nuxt": "^3.7.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.29",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "storybook": "^7.4.1",
    "storybook-addon-nuxt": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "pinia": "^2.1.6"
  }
}
```

and the `.storybook/main.ts`

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/vue3-vite";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [
    "../stories/**/*.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "storybook-addon-nuxt",
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/vue3-vite",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
};
export default config;
```

and the `.storybook/preview.ts`

```
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/vue3";

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;
```

i tried many ways to solve the issue, when i run command `yarn storybook` it throw this error:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ storybook dev -p 6006
@storybook/cli v7.4.1

WARN   Failed to load preset: {"type":"presets","name":"/Users/alirezahamid/Documents/Apps/nuxt-atomic/node_modules/storybook-addon-nuxt/dist/preset.js"} on level 1
./node_modules/storybook-addon-nuxt/dist/preset.js:1
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Object.newLoader (./node_modules/esbuild-register/dist/node.js:2262:9)
    at extensions..js (./node_modules/esbuild-register/dist/node.js:4838:24)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
WARN   Failed to load preset: {"type":"presets","name":"/Users/alirezahamid/Documents/Apps/nuxt-atomic/node_modules/storybook-addon-nuxt/dist/preset.js"} on level 1
./node_modules/storybook-addon-nuxt/dist/preset.js:1
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Object.newLoader (./node_modules/esbuild-register/dist/node.js:2262:9)
    at extensions..js (./node_modules/esbuild-register/dist/node.js:4838:24)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
info => Starting manager..
╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                   │
│   Storybook 7.4.1 for vue3-vite started           │
│   266 ms for manager and 885 ms for preview       │
│                                                   │
│    Local:            http://localhost:6006/       │
│    On your network:  http://192.168.1.83:6006/    │
│                                                   │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
✘ [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/esm/_interop/dtl.js:2:7:
      2 │ import def__default from '@testing-library/dom';
        ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~~~

/Users/alirezahamid/Documents/Apps/nuxt-atomic/node_modules/@storybook/cli/bin/index.js:23
  throw error;
  ^

Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/esm/_interop/dtl.js:2:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js" for import "default"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/alirezahamid/Documents/Apps/nuxt-atomic/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1649:15)
    at /Users/alirezahamid/Documents/Apps/nuxt-atomic/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1058:25
    at /Users/alirezahamid/Documents/Apps/nuxt-atomic/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1525:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 7,
        file: 'node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/esm/_interop/dtl.js',
        length: 12,
        line: 2,
        lineText: "import def__default from '@testing-library/dom';",
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'No matching export in "node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js" for import "default"'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}

Node.js v18.17.0
```

Thanks for your solutions and i appreciate your time.

Comment: Please give a read to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+use+import+statement+outside+a+module

Comment: Facing same issue, i've seen this "fix" but i don't know how/where to apply https://github.com/hirotaka/storybook-addon-nuxt/issues/24

Comment: for the issue: https://github.com/hirotaka/storybook-addon-nuxt/issues/24

It says on the first line: "add "type": "module", to the package.json file inside the storybook-addon-nuxt folder."